# Java, bootstrap and extension classes

Tags: java

I'm new to java and under [Cross-Compilation Options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#crosscomp-options) there is a part that says:

> By default, classes are compiled against the bootstrap and extension classes

What are the `bootstrap and extension classes`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracles docs give some insight:

> The Java launcher, **java**, initiates the Java virtual machine. The virtual machine searches for and loads classes in this order:
>
> - **Bootstrap classes** - Classes that comprise the Java platform, including the classes in rt.jar and several other important jar files.
> - **Extension classes** - Classes that use the Java Extension mechanism. These are bundled as .jar files located in the extensions directory.
> - **User classes** - Classes defined by developers and third parties that do not take advantage of the extension mechanism. You identify the location of these classes using the -classpath option on the command line (the preferred method) or by using the CLASSPATH environment variable. (See Setting the Classpath for Windows or Unix.)

[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html)

Your Java Development Kit (JDK) comes with a set of bootstrap and extension classes. When you compile java with this JDK, these classes in their specific versions will be used for compilation.

Comment: I understand, thank you TimoSta, ill accept in 1min or so ;)